# scala filter by type

Tags: scala, generics, runtime-type

I have read `TypeTag` related article, but I am unable to realize filter a collection by elements type.

Example:

```
trait A
class B extends A
class C extends A

val v = Vector(new B,new C)
v filter ( _.isInstanceOf[B] )
```

The code above works fine.
However I want to extract `filter` out of `v`. E.g.

```
def filter[T,T2](data:Traversable[T2]) = (data filter (  _.isInstanceOf[T])).asInstanceOf[Traversable[T]]

//Then filter v by
filter[B,A](v)
```

In this case I get warning `abstract type T is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure`. I tried to use `TypeTag`, but it seems not easy to get `Type` on runtime.

Is there any elegant solution to realize function `filter`?
Any solution via scala macro is also acceptable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to provide a `ClassTag`, not a `TypeTag`, and use pattern matching.  `ClassTags` work well with pattern matching.  You can even use the `collect` method to perform the `filter` and `map` together:

```
def filter[T, T2](data: Traversable[T2])(implicit ev: ClassTag[T]) = data collect {
    case t: T => t
}
```

For example:

```
val data = Seq(new B, new B, new C, new B)
filter[B, A](data) //Traversable[B] with length 3
filter[C, A](data) //Traversable[C] with length 1
```

One problem with this is that it might not work as expected with nested generic types.

The `collect` method takes in a parameter of type `PartialFunction`, representing a function that does not need to be defined on the entire domain.  When using `collect` elements where the `PartialFunction` is undefined are filtered out, and elements that matched some `case` statement are mapped accordingly.

You can also use [existential types](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#existential-types) and let the compiler deduce the type of the `data` parameter for a more concise syntax.  You can also use [context bounds](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-and-view-bounds.html):

```
def filter[T : ClassTag](data: Traversable[_]) = data collect { case t: T => t }
filter[B](data)
```

One problem with the methods here is that there is a significant difference between the native `filter` method you have: these methods always returns a `Traversable` while the native `filter` returns the best type it can.  For example:

```
val data = Vector(new B, new B, new C, new B)
data filter { _.isInstanceOf[B] } //Vector[A]
data filter { _.isInstanceOf[B] } map { _.asInstanceOf[B] } //Vector[B]
data collect { case t: B => t } //Vector[B].  Note that if you know the type at the calling point, this is pretty concise and might not need a helper method at all

//As opposed to:
filter[B](data) //Traversable[B], not a Vector!
```

You can fix this by using the [`CanBuildFrom`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom) pattern using another implicit parameter.  You can also use [implicit classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html) to essentially add the method to the class (as opposed to calling the method in the static style shown above).  This all adds up to a pretty complicated method, but I'll leave it here if you're interested in these enhancements:

```
implicit class RichTraversable[T2, Repr <: TraversableLike[T2, Repr], That](val trav: TraversableLike[T2, Repr]) extends AnyVal {
    def withType[T : ClassTag](implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, T, That]) = trav.collect {
        case t: T => t
    }
}
```

This would allow you to do:

```
data.withType[B] //Vector[B], as desired
```

Comment: Hi @BenReich, Thank you for your nice answer. Could you explain more about the syntax `{ case t: B => t }` of `data collect { case t: B => t }`?  Why you don't need to provide an exhaustive pattern match there?

Comment: @worldterminator I've added a small edit explaining `collect` a little bit more.

Comment: @BenReich Thanks, the last piece of code is exactly what I needed. It is also a perfect example of the possibilities of Scala and the difficulty of its type system and collection library. I hope to master stuff like that soon.

Answer (score 0):

There must definitely be an easier way. The below works but I would hope even for a simpler solution

```
trait A
case class B()
case class C()
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.util.Try
val m = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
def filter[T](data:Traversable[_])(implicit t:TypeTag[T]) = data collect {
      case i if Try(i.getClass.asSubclass(m.runtimeClass(typeOf[T].typeSymbol.asClass))).isSuccess => i.asInstanceOf[T]
    }
val v= Vector(new B,new C)

scala>     println(filter[B](v))
Vector(B()) //This gets printed
```